# Left over application in GKE - how to remove and make webpreview work as before

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I deployed an application (let's say app1) in GKE with a service, deployment and certificate setup in an existing cluster with Jenkins and another app (let's say app2).
The other app is deployed in the same way as the new one, with a certificate (and a static IP and DNS entry).

Jenkins is not exposed to an external IP, so I used to use the port forward option in the cloud console and then web preview - this creates an appspot URL which alloww me to login to the web admin.

Something strange happened after I deployed app2.
I tested it with the webpreview button and could reach it.
All was fine and it was accessible at the new URL with HTTPS and all.
But after that, the web preview to Jenkins was not working anymore.
Instead, I would be redirected to app2, always.

I could not figure out why, so I removed everything from app2 and now I have some very strange situation:

- in the (Chrome) browser where I did most of the actions, I can still access the (broken) app on both the FQDN in DNS and on the appspot link ( https://8080-dot-1234567-dot-devshell.appspot.com/ even after I reboot, clear cache and logout the google account (and removed the statis IP even) - the port forward actions works and gives the above link (with other numbers)
- in another (Chromium) browser on the same laptop running Ubuntu, the portford action works, but when clicking the link in the browser it does not generate another appsot url and fails with a 500 error screen

After reading up a bit, I understand there is some proxy that is used to do the forward, I expect the proxy to be 'hanging' some how and on top of that it seems there are application left overs in the cluster that should really not be there

I have basic support currently, so not eligable for technical support.
I cannot find a manual way to access the appspot proxy and I found no load balancer or any other thing I know of that may cause this.

If I run the portfoward in the cloud shell in the second browser, I can curl to the localhost on the exposed port and get Jenkins, so that part seems to work, but the web preview then does not.

How can I go about troubleshooting this (meaning getting back to the web preview working for Jenkins and getting rid of the application left overs)?

Comment: Well its hard to tell. What did you deploy with first and second app? GKE resources, Ingress, Services, etc? How did you deploy it. Without specific information It will be hard to answer this.

Comment: Hi,app1 (nodejs custom app) is deployed via the cloud console, by selecting a docker image and a certifcate like https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs.
App2 is yopass: https://github.com/jhaals/yopass, deployed based on the files supplied, but with a deployment,service, certificate and ingress. yopass deployment caused it and is left over after completely removing. Reported to Google too: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/163610913 .

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the cause of this issue with the help of a colleague.
The second application I deployed was Yopass.
It turned out that it uses a serviceworker, that cached (almost) everything in the browser, including most of the application, I suppose to run offline.

Although I tried clearing cache in the network tab in developer options, I still had this behaviour which made me think it was not a cache issue.
After removing all cache in the applications tab for both the FQDN url and the appspot domain, behavior went back to normal.

I was not able to fix it in the other browser yet, but I suppose that is cache too. Thanks for the help, I consider this solved.